# How to update table1 field by using other table and function

Tags: oracle, update, plsql, functions

I have two tables and one function:

Table1 contains `shop_code,batch_id`

```
shop_code| batch_id  | regstriy_id
123 | 100  | 12
124 | 100  |13
125 | 100  |12
```

Table2 contains `shop_code,shop_name`

```
shop_code| shop_name  
123 | need to populate  
124 | need to populate  
125 | need to populate
```

Function1 take parameter `registry_id` from table1 and returns `shop_name`

Table2 `shop_name` is empty I want to populate against the `shop_code`.

It will be great if someone can help, I am using Oracle.

I tried this but not working

```
 update TABLE2 set T2.SHOP_NAME = T.SHOP_NAME
 from(
 select GET_shop_name(t1.regitry_id) as shop_name ,
           t1.shop_code shop_code
           from TABLE1 T1 
                ) t where t.shop_code = t1.shop_code;
```

Comment: i'm unclear as to what you want. Are you saying you want to update the shop_name in table2 to be the batch_id from table1, matching on shop_code?

Comment: @davegreen100 I update my question please help

Comment: where is GET_SHOP_NAME getting the shop_name from? it can't be from table2 as this is what you are trying to populate

Comment: GET_shop_name is a function which takes parameter of registry_id and return shop name

Comment: i may be being dumb, but where does it get shop_name from?

Comment: GET_shop_name is a function which takes parameter of registry_id and return shop name, The function have a 250 lines of code to find out the shop_name and interacts with 12 tables.

Comment: in which case i would go for answer 1 below from @a1ex07

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it in Oracle.  Right of the bat I can think about two.

1. Straightforward, not Oracle specific (assuming shop_code is unique in `table1`)

   ```
   update TABLE2 t2 set SHOP_NAME = 
   (
     SELECT GET_shop_name(t1.regitry_id)  
     FROM TABLE1 T1 
     WHERE t2.shop_code = t1.shop_code
   );
   ```
2. Oracle specific syntax(requires inline view to be key-preserved - if `shop_code` is not a PK column in both tables you will very likely get "SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table" )

   ```
   UPDATE
    (
       SELECT GET_shop_name(t1.regitry_id) AS new_name,
              t2.shop_code, t2.shop_name
       FROM TABLE2 t2 
       INNER JOIN t1 ON (t2.shop_code = t1.shop_code)
     )
   SET shop_name = new_name;
   ```

Comment: Thanks `shop_code` is primary key in both